# Can't convert time.struct_time to json-compatible format

Tags: python, json

When I convert this

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2014, tm_mon=11, tm_mday=30, tm_hour=4, tm_min=50, tm_sec=8, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=334, tm_isdst=0)
```

into a JSON object, it throws an error saying it can't serialize it. I didn't find an answer how to do this. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it to a string using [`time.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) and then dump:

```
>>> import json
>>> import time
>>> 
>>> struct = time.localtime()
>>> type(struct)
<type 'time.struct_time'>
>>> time_string = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', struct)
>>> 
>>> print json.dumps({'time': time_string})
{"time": "2014-11-30 04:26:26"}
```